# nginx how to host both react and django

Tags: python, reactjs, django, nginx, gunicorn

i have a react frontend imported inside a django backend. communication between the two is done through `django-rest-framework`. on the react's side, fetching is done through relative paths therefore in my `package.json` i have added the line:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
```

django is hosting react-app locally without problems when i run: `python3 manage.py runserver`.

on the remote i am trying to use `nginx` with `gunicorn` to deploy this app on aws ubuntu instance and run into the problem:

- first, i'm running `python3 manage.py collectstatic`
- later, i'm pointing nginx to that static_files for the index.html
- **success!** nginx serves react static files
- use `gunicorn myapp.wsgi -b 127.0.0.1:8000` to run django
- **problem!** nginx served react files do not fetch anything. fetch does not call for this local path but instead calls public ip of aws instance. also, i cannot simulate get/post requests to the django backend because i think nginx "covers" django's gunicorn generated paths.

please tell how can i connect nginx-served react frontedn to gunicorn run django

my nginx sites-enabled/example

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /home/ubuntu/fandigger/frontend/build/;
    server_name public_ip_without_port;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this inside the `server` block in the nginx settings: `location /static { alias /my/path/to/static; }` and that routes it. Most of the guides I followed said to do it, so give that a shot

Comment: oh, i think i have tried that but got some error when rebooting nginx. do you have remove ‘root’ from nginx for that ?

Comment: Check out [This](https://austinogiza.medium.com/deploying-react-and-django-rest-framework-with-nginx-and-gunicorn-7a0553459500), It looks like you make two different nginx available sites- 1 for react.js and 1 for django.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was trying in the first place but had some troubles with it and switched

Comment: Oh yeah, like hardly any guides work right out of the box from my experience. I'd say try just ploping in my alias thing in the current example.conf and see what happens- just start throwing stuff against the wall, somethin will stick eventually lol.